# Microsoft Azure external domain {x} working but not www.{x}

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a domain {x} hosted by Lws and a web app hosted by Microsoft Azure. I managed to import the domain {x} in Microsoft Azure by adding the required DNS records A and CNAME in Lws, and I also imported an SSL certificate successfully.

So my domain {x} is correctly configured and can be accessed with the url https://{x}. But if I type www.{x} in my web browser, I'm getting an error from Microsoft Azure: "Error 404 - Web app not found.".

I tried to add the domain 'www.{x}' in addition to the domain '{x}' in the Azure portal but it didn't fix the problem.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this error with the url www.{x}?

Comment: Just curious - Have you done the CNAME mapping of `www` to `yourwebapp.azurewebsites.net`? Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/.

Comment: So you have a CNAME for www at Lws?

Comment: Yes I followed the instructions from Azure documentation. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just had to wait to fix my problem, adding the domain 'www.{x}' in addition to the domain '{x}' in the Azure portal was the solution, but it was only effective after several hours (or maybe it was due to the cache of my browser).